# Firefox Shrinking flash object down to 14px, chrome and IE fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I currently have a Script that shows a Youtube link on a user click, which works fine in Both Chrome and IE, but it forces the object height to be 14 pixels everytime in Firefox.

```
.popup {
z-index: 18;
position:fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%); 
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
background-color: #4D8DBE;
border-radius: 8px;
border-style:double;
border-width:4px;
border-color: #125E98;
box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 10px 4px #125E98;
visibility: hidden;
padding:15px;
}
```

and on the user click, it'll make that visible, and add in the relevant embed code.

```
function RenderVideo() {
document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = '<object width="720" height="405"><param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/' + theVideoURL[Rand] + '?autoplay=1&controls=0&disablekb=1&modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&version=3"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param><embed id="ytplayer" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/' + theVideoURL[Rand] + '?autoplay=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&controls=0&enablejsapi=1&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0' + theExtras[Rand] + '&showinfo=0&autohide=1&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="720" height="405"></embed></object>';
```

}

In chrome, this renders correctly, with the video popping up in the middle with 15px padding, but in firefox, the Div pops up in the correct size, but the object just hides in the bottom of the div at 14px tall.

is there anything that firefox needs to be able to render the video correctly?

http://jsbin.com/zetoradexe/2/ is the minified version of what it does.

[EDIT] I found what was causing the Issue of the video not appearing in firefox, and it was the transform command (I was using it to centre the div itself), so i guess i'll have to find a new way to center my div.

Comment: can you make this a minimal runnable example? (either as jsbin or as an in-stackoverflow-runnable-code example?)

Comment: Yeah, just in the process of doing that now

Comment: [Here's a basic version of what it does](http://jsbin.com/zetoradexe/2/), This was working for me, once again in Chrome and IE, but the actual object itself is Invisible in Firefox.

Comment: no, don't put that in the comments. Please put that in the post, it's information that others need to be able to see without needing to read a comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you generally don't put a long HTML string inside your JS, because the JS engine won't tell you the HTML is mangled when it is, as it is here. Instead, you put it in something like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="loadtemplate">
  ...
</script>
```

and then you load it in by grabbing that content and injecting it. In this case it's relatively straight forward to see where things go wrong simply by doing an inspect element:

```
<object "style="height: 100%;" width="720" height="405">
```

Hello, rogue double quote.

Fixing that, let's also fix the in-JS HTML and styling. Don't do that. Put the embed code in the HTML and swap it in from there, and don't use `.style.... = ...`, use classes and toggle them with `.classList.add` and `.classList.remove`:

http://jsbin.com/zalosurotu/2/

Comment: There's a stray Double Quote, and i appreciate that this probably isn't the best way to go about it, (i've been doing JS/webdev for about 3 weeks now) but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: see updated post. I rewrote your code so that it follows some good practices like "never put HTML in JS" and "never fiddle with `style` in JS if you can use classes)

Comment: The main problem with that code, is that it's not always a Video, and it's not always that video when it is a video. I've got a bunch of arrays that i inject into that code, so i guess i'll have to figure out some way to leave the two seperate.

Comment: sure but that's a whole other problem. You can always grab the script element, and then affect changes with `element.querySelector(...).setAttribute` etc.